# What does lock screen do exactly?

Tags: lock-screen

I am debugging a very rare and random bug in my application and I found out the bug happens every time I lock the screen and then unlock it. I would like to know what exactly happens during the lock screen process. So I have a bunch of related questions.

How do I find out which program is locking the screen?
How exactly does it do that?
Is there any event sent through the system? Any signal?
Are any devices being unpowered during the process?

I mostly want to know how to find out these things myself. I genuinely don't know where to look.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Another option could be to post the bug as a question and seeking answers.

Comment: That would be far too complicated I think.

Comment: Ok well I'm on phone now but if you search here on `lock-screen-timer` you should find Q&A where I used `dbus` to lock the screen and it works without bugs.